# Is it true that $E[X_n^2] \to E[X^2]$ as $n \to \infty$ implies $E[X_n^2 1_A] \to E[X^2 1_A]$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: probability-theory

Is it true that $E[X_n^2] \to E[X^2]$ as $n \to \infty$(we also have that $X_n \to X \text{ in } L^2$) implies  $E[X_n^2 1_A] \to E[X^2 1_A]$ as $n \to \infty$ 
My attempt

I can show that $E[X_{n_k}^2 1_A] \to E[X^2 1_A]$ as $k \to \infty$ for some subsequence $(n_k)_{k \ge 1}$. Indeed using that $X_n \to X \text{ in } L^2$ implies $X_{n_k} \to X$ a.s. as $k \to \infty$ and also $1_AX_{n_k} \to 1_AX$ a.s. as $k \to \infty$  and the genralized lebesgue dominated theorem (http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-generalized-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem )yields $E[X_{n_k}^2 1_A] \to E[X^2 1_A]$ as $k \to \infty$

How can I show this along the first sequence? Is it even true?

Comment: $X_n \to X$ in $L^2$ implies $E(X_n^2 1_A) \to E(X^2 1_A)$ for any measurable set $A$; however convergence of the norms (i.e. $E(X_n^2) \to E(X^2)$) is not enough to conclude that $E(X_n^2 1_A) \to E(X^2 1_A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\delta_n=|\mathbb{E}[X_n^21_A]-\mathbb{E}[X^21_A]| \leq \mathbb{E}[1_A|X_n^2-X^2|] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n^2-X^2|].$$

Now, $$|X_n^2-X^2|\leq |X_n-X| (|X_n|+|X|) \leq \frac{|X_n-X|^2}{2\epsilon_n}+\epsilon_n(|X_n|+|X|)^2/2 \leq \frac{|X_n-X|^2}{2\epsilon_n}+\epsilon_n|X_n|^2+\epsilon_n|X|^2$$ for any sequence $\epsilon_n > 0$.

Therefore, with $\epsilon_n=\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]^{1/2}$, since the expected values of $X_n$ and $X$ are bounded by some $M>0$, we get 
$\delta_n \leq \epsilon_n(1+2M) \rightarrow 0$.